# Test data generation : simulating work day of an employee

Tags: python

I am trying to generate some test data through python. (my app is not in python but python seems easy and succinct for data generation). I want to simulate a typical work day of an employee, by generating 'time slots' of activities. Below function needs to generate '`n`' number of time slot between `start` and `end`(with some random gap between to seem natural) with a `total`(total_hrs).

```
slots = [] #list of slot == {start:<>, end:<>}
def time_slot(start, end, n, total_hrs):
  # generate n non-overlapping time slot between start and end (with some random gap between to seem natural)

print (slots)
```

Eg:

```
time_slot( "1/1/2013 9:00", "1/1/2013 17:00", 3, 8)

[ {start: "1/1/2013 9:00", end: "1/1/2013 10:30"}, ...., {start: "1/1/2013 14:00", end: "1/1/2013 16:44"}]

#total time == 8
```

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous. I am not proficient in python and was looking for pointers/examples to write this function to generate time slots. hope the std library (time, random) and list manipulation facilities make this task easier (which I am not exposed to). I could think of doing this with bunch of for loops but hope an expert python user may help me to see a better way to do this in python.

Comment: Well, one for loop would be enough I think. Loop through it n times, and generate a slot and a break for each. Done.

Comment: thanks. I will dig into python library doc. my worry was manipulating time (adding fractions based on total_time/n (also randomize to avoid uniform slot), also adding random gaps between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give an outline of what I would do:

1. draw `n` random numbers
2. `s = sum all numbers`
3. convert `total_hrs` to `total_min`
4. make the work-chunks: `chunks = [c/s * total_min for c in numbers]`
5. calc the difference between `end - start` and `total_hrs`
6. do the same steps 1 - 4 again for this difference to get the gaps (use n+1 to allow for a gap at the beginning
7. Finally convert all the chunks to `datetime.timedelta` and add the timedelta consecutively to start (already at the beginning you should have converted `start` and `end` to `datetime.date`)

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing out the availability of datetime.timedelta . that makes it easier to add duration